# How to put a system environment variables as a macro definitions to a C header file?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, macros

Is there any **simple** way to fill a header file with the macro definitions corresponding to a list of an environment variables?

Let's say I have something like a template of the header file:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DEFINES_H__INCLUDED
#define DEFINES_H__INCLUDED

//{{
// I want to place the #defines here...
//}}

#endif // DEFINES_H__INCLUDED
```

Now I could to check if some environment variables (in bounds of a predefined set) are defined in the system and put the corresponding `#define` into this header. I.e. if there is the `_SOME_VAR` I want to put the `#define _SOME_VAR` into the header. And the same with other vars.

I need not to do this task exactly in this way. In general I need to build my program depending on something like the environment vars or something else. I build it using the `make` utility, but I can not to change a `makefile`'s content because it is generated automatically.

I see that I ask about something like making the `config.h` from `config.in` in the `autoconf`, but I need not so heavy tool to do so simple (at the first look) task.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How will Makefile be generated?

Comment: @Danh, by the Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @SergeRoussak add it to the question, guy

Comment: Did you try to #ifdef, #undef then #define?

Comment: @khôinguyễn, I am not quite understood what do you mean.

Comment: I used to face a similar trouble but in Visual studio and I found a place to add/remove the preprocessor definition (but I don't know how to change its value). I think you can try to find similar thing in Eclipse CDT.

Comment: You check if the varible existence by #ifdef, then if it exists you can #undef it and define it again #define. But it's silly idea, since these are "system ENVIRONMENT" variable.

Comment: @SergeRoussak it is relatively easy to generate said config file with a shell script (that requires at least knowing what shell you're going to use).

Comment: @khôinguyễn, the thing in that I develop my program in Eclipse only, but then it need to be build from sources at the different platforms. Because of this I had not specify about the Eclipse nor post the makefile in my question. I.e., let's say the makefile in my case is something like a black box (or how does it sounds in English?).

Comment: @SergeRoussak Then why you need to modify system environment variables? Different platform don't share too much of them. Anyway, if you can find the preprocessor definition, then the generated makefile will works similar to keine Lust below.

Comment: Just a small issue, You are using double compilation guards: `#pragma once` and `#ifndef #define`. `#pragma once` is now in the standard, so You can use only this one

Comment: @SzałPał is it? Which standard? (sorry for unrelated comment; totally agree that only one thing should be used, both makes no sense, but shouldn't actually hurt)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the preprocessor options: ["/D"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) on Visual Studio or ["-D"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) on gcc

An example passing the `$HOME` environment variable using `gcc`

```
gcc -std=c11 -o demo demo.c -DMY_HOME=\"$HOME\"
```

You can pass multiple variables:

```
gcc -std=c11 -o demo demo.c -DMY_HOME=\"$HOME\" -DMY_USER=\"$USER\"
```

Comment: I would suggest using `-DMY_HOME_=\"$HOME\"` instead, since `_MY_HOME` is reserved name, using it is an undefined behavior

Comment: I know about the `-D` option, but I can't to adjust the command line in my case (see above).

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Project->Properties and select C/C++ Build->Settings.
Find under Tool settings, the preprocessor -D options. Add your desired environment_variable here. This will add -Denvironment_variable to your build script.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal variant is to put this lines to the `makefile.defs` in the project dir:

```
ifdef PLATFORM
CFLAGS:=-D$(PLATFORM)
endif
```

and to add the `$(CFLAGS)` to the "Other flags" field at the Properties of the project > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings > Miscellaneous.

Thanks to all who answered.